# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Tags: python

a'$'

```
money=1000000;
portfolio=0;
value=0;
value=(yahoostock.get_price('RIL.BO'));
portfolio=(16*(value));
print id(portfolio);
print id(value);
money= (money-portfolio);
'''
```

I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dee/dee.py", line 12, in <module>
    money= (value-portfolio);
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Since money is integer and so is portfolio, I cant solve this problem..anyone can help???

Comment: Why are you printing the ids?  Did you mean to look at type(portfolio)?

Comment: Your python has been attacked by the semicolon monster!

Comment: Apparently, Python does not allow you to subtract one string from another.

Comment: +1 to counteract needless -1.

Answer (score 6):

```
value=(yahoostock.get_price('RIL.BO'));
```

Apparently returns a string not a number. Convert it to a number:

```
value=int(yahoostock.get_price('RIL.BO'));
```

Also the signal-to-noise ratio isn't very high. You've lots of (,), and ; you don't need. You assign variable only to replace them on the next line. You can make your code nicer like so:

```
money = 1000000
value = int(yahoostock.get_price('RIL.BO'));
portfolio = 16 * value;
print id(portfolio);
print id(value);
money -= portfolio;
```

Answer (score 5):

`money` and `portfolio` are apparently strings, so cast them to ints:

```
money= int( float(money)-float(portfolio) )
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error message clearly states, both are string, cast with `int(var)`.

Note:

Let's see what can we decude from the error message:

`portfolio` must be string(`str`), which means `value` is also a string. Like this:

```
>>> 16*"a"
'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
```

and apparently you missed to post relevant code because the error message tells you that `money` is str as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is assuming that because you have initialised variables with integer values they will remain as integers.  Python doesn't work this way.  Assigning a value with `=` only binds the name to the value without paying any attention to type.  For example:

```
a = 1       # a is an int
a = "Spam!" # a is now a str
```

I assume `yahoostock.getprice()`, like many functions that get data from websites, returns a string.  You need to convert this using `int()` before doing your maths.