# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object-(a,No_ofsides=areacalculation(EN_data)

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, visual-studio-code

The purpose is to read coordinates from a file, it survey traverse. The following is what it is supposed to do:

```
#Start at point A and going clockwise around the traverse list the coordinates:
#Cross multiply in one direction; 500.000*2000.000=647,228.0
#Cross multiply in the other direction; 
#Add up the columns of the products which is 3,384,174.1 |3,590,045.6
#Using Area Equation to compute the area; difference of 2 columns divided by 2


 
#Point file contains 
    #Point,N,E
    #A,500.000,2000.000 
    #B,323.614,1561.426 
    #C,526.996,1488.321 
    #D,719.336,1686.956 
       
    import math, os, csv

        #Reading the file from here
        def getcoord():
            
            myfile= input('Enter the path of file : ')
            filename = 'CoordsT.txt'
            with open('filename', 'r') as csvfile:
                reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
                next(reader)
                return list(reader)
                data=[]
                for row in reader:
                    Name=row[0]
                    E=float(row[1])
                    N=float(row[2])
                    data.append([Name,E,N])
                return data
        
        def areacalculation(data): #function that calculate the area of polygon
            n=len(data)
            semiarea= 0.0
            j = n - 1#
            if n>=3:
                for i in range(0,n):
                    semiarea += (data[j][1] + data[i][1]) * (data[j][2]- data[i][2])
                    j = i # j is previous vertex to i
                    area=abs(semiarea/2.0)
                    return area,n
            else:
                print('Enter  at least 3 sides of polygon')
        
        def polygontype(n): #function that gives the type of polygon, takes argument
            dictionary={3:"Triangle",4:"Quadrilateral",5:"Pentagon",6:"Hexagon",7:"Heptagon",8:"Octagon",9:"Nonagon"}
            b=dictionary[n]
            return b
        
        def square_metre(area):     #function with argument
            A2=int(area)
            return (A2)
            
        def hectares(area):   # fuction with argument
            A1=area 
            return "%.4f"%(A1)
        #the error am getting comes from this block
        def main():
            instruction()
            EN_data= getcoord()
            a,No_ofsides=areacalculation(EN_data)  #the problem is here
            hectares(a)
            sqm=square_metre(a)
            polytyp=polygontype(No_ofsides)
        
            return EN_data
            
            if a>10000:
                area_hec=hectares(a/10000.00)
                print('The area of',polytyp,'is',area_hec,'Hectares')
            else:
                print('The area of',polytyp,'is',sqm,'Square Metres')
        main()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653403/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-str-and-str)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like the issue is:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str' on "semiarea += (data[j][1] + data[i][1]) * (data[j][2]- data[i][2])"

I think you need something like

```
semiarea += (float(data[j][1]) + float(data[i][1])) * (float(data[j][2]) - float(data[i][2]))
```